# setExpirationTimeInterval doesn't work on parse.com

Tags: android, notifications, parse-platform, push

Im try to send a push with  Expiration Time Interval but it doesn't send to service

```
long weekInterval = 60*60*24*7; // 1 week

            // Send push notification with expiration interval
            ParsePush push1 = new ParsePush();
            push1.setExpirationTime(weekInterval);
            push1.setQuery(ParseInstallation.getQuery().whereEqualTo("deviceType", "android"));
            push1.setMessage("Season tickets on sale until November 20th");
            push1.sendInBackground();
```

but on server side in description of notification is this

> Targeting :
>
> ```
> deviceType is "android"
> Sending date :
> November 14th, 2014 at 5:42 PM
> Expiration :
> None
> Full target :
> { "deviceType": "android" }
> Full data :
> { "alert": "Season tickets on sale until November 20th" }
> ```

As you see Expiration is **None**

**UPDATED:**
The same behaviour is with:
**setExpirationTimeInterval()**

is it my bug or service's?

Comment: I seem to receive pushes that should have been expired as well. I am sending from Cloud Code.

Comment: I have tested your code and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use:

[setExpirationTimeInterval()](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePush.html#setExpirationTimeInterval(long))

instead of setExpirationTime()

(which sets a specific timestamp instead of a duration)